# How to intercept all window features passed to window.open in WebView2?

Tags: winforms, window.open, webview2

I'm guessing I might just have to create an issue on their repo, but how does one access the raw string (or dictionary) of features that gets passed to `window.open`?

In Electron, I could intercept `window.open` via [`setWindowOpenHandler`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler) and then access `details.features` to get all the features passed in (even those that weren't part of the spec).

In Webview2, I intercept the [`NewWindowRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.newwindowrequested?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.2210.55) event. The passed-in args have a `WindowFeatures` property, but it's a typed as a [`CoreWebView2WindowFeatures`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2windowfeatures?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.2210.55) and only includes a few properties.

Is there no way to grab all the features passed into window.open?